# how to save/fetch non English characters into core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have successfully added and fetched some data using core data. my entity attribute has the following scheme: productName, price and quantity.

price and quantity are displayed correctly in the console. On the other hand, product name is written in Arabic and therefore it is displayed in weird characters like: "\U062c\U064a\U0628 \U0627\U0644\U062a\U0627\U062c\U0631";

save to core data code:

```
   @IBAction func submitOrderButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let newItem =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "OrderDetail", into: context)
    newItem.setValue(String(self.productName.text!), forKey: "productName")
    newItem.setValue(Int(self.productPrice.text!), forKey: "price")
    newItem.setValue(self.orderQuantity, forKey: "quantity")

    do{
        try context.save()
    }
    catch{
        // display in a uialert message
        print("error has occured")
    }
    print("\(orderQuantity) items of this product")

}
```

fetch from core data code:

```
    func fetchOrderDetails(){

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context =  appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchedOrders = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OrderDetail")
    fetchedOrders.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false


    do{
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchedOrders)
        if result.count > 0{
            print()
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
}
```

output in console:

```
<OrderDetail: 0x604000480af0> (entity: OrderDetail; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://109134CB-DCF5-45D8-9298-E8B43C51E5DA/OrderDetail/p1> ; data: {
price = 3;
productName = "\U062c\U064a\U0628 \U0627\U0644\U062a\U0627\U062c\U0631";
quantity = 2;
  })
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

All I did was access the attributes and then I could either assign it to a label or print it in the console. Both worked.
Below is the code I added:

```
        do{
        let result = try context.fetch(fetchedOrders)
        if result.count > 0{
          // added code
            var tempProd = result[0] as! NSManagedObject
            productName.text = "\(tempProd.value(forKey: "productName"))"

            for data in result as! [NSManagedObject]{
                print(data.value(forKey: "productName") as! String)

            }
           // end of added code
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's the way Xcode shows special characters. Your data is probably fine. What happens if you try to show the product name in a label?

Comment: The console output is irrelevant. print `productName` or assign the value to a label then you will see the proper characters.

Comment: yes, you guys are right, I assigned the value to a label and it was printed correctly.